# Prevent other processes and users from accessing a file

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a windows service written in C# running on a machine and it creates and uses a number of files. Is there a way to prevent a user on the machine, administrators included, from messing with these files(moving, editing, renaming, deleting) from the code?

I know that StreamWriter can achieve this, but **I don't want to keep the files open all the time** without the need to actually access the data in them, but I can't seem to find any other way.

**EDIT:** Let me rephrase the question base don the comments below. Is there a way to setup ACL in a way that only my service can access the files? I would also accept if only services could access the files(I have seen mention of All Services security group in Microsoft Docs but I can't seem to actually find it on the system or in .net).

Comment: You can't "protect" your code from Administrators on a machine. If your "adversary" is a machine's administrator, then the only safe move is to *not put the things that the adversary wants on that machine*. I.e. you should be looking at some form of remote storage.

Comment: @bommelding - indeed. And when an administrator has the power to do many things, including *debugging into other processes on the same machine, no matter what account that process is running under*, they can do plenty of messing. They can inject any code they want *into* the OPs process.

Comment: Please bear in mind that blocking access to a file by keeping it constantly opened in the process is pure madness and against any rule of decent programming! If you apply this ever it will hurt you sooner than later.

Comment: "I don't want to keep the files open all the time" - why? If those files are created by your program, and only used by your program - I don't see any problem in that.

Comment: @Alexander do you want to prevent admin to mess with them "by case" or on purpose? In the second case, as Damien already said, you're probably out of luck. In the first case access permissions and flags will at least make them aware they're doing something potentially dangerous

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not worried about protecting my code or the content of the files, the issue is that if someone messes with the files I get inconsistent behaviour because I end up working with wrong data. I just want to stop users from messing with the files.

Comment: @bommelding There are many reasons why. First and foremost is that you keep system resources (pointers to file) at constant use for no cause. FileStream is IDisposable so ideally it should be used within using(). If you keep your file open, saves something to it and the app crashes the file may not contain your changes. You have your files open, but what if you app automatically recycles? Then all your files are free again. I can go on with it the whole day.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Which flags do you mean? I've messed with ACL permissions but I can't find one which works for me, since ACL is user/group based, I haven't been able to find a setting that doesn't also stop me from reading the file.

Comment: Then you need to relax your constraints slightly. Administrators are trusted to mess with files because, ultimately, [windows lets users win over programs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040216-00/?p=40603). And who knows, maybe something *does* need correcting with those files to *allow* your program to work correctly. Who's going to do that if not the administrators?

Comment: If you don't like to keep them open - put them in some folder (for example under `%APPDATA%`) where users are unlikely to mess with them by accident. If they got there and still messed with them - well, then they had a reason to.

Comment: @Evk They are in such a path, but I wanted to add just an extra bit of protection in case someone does end up in there.

Comment: @AleksandarMalovic I'd say if they end up there - they know what they are doing (or at least they think they know), there is no need to hold-hand them. I can hardly imagine situation when user somehow figured out where your application stores important files, went there, deleted some of them, and then complained to you that application is broken.

Comment: If you dont want anyone messing with them, encrypt them and it would make no sense to anyone to even try to change the content.

Comment: @Magnus Content is already encrypted, but someone can still open it in notepad++, add a few characters, and the files becomes useless.

Comment: Put your files in a directory called, PleaseDontMessWithTheseFilesOrThereBeDragons, mark them has hidden, Or keep the handles open

Comment: @AleksandarMalovic They can also open your programs exe file and mess with that and your program would become useless, but would they really?

Comment: Is this a security issue, or is more because you have lots of sneaky admins

Comment: @AleksandarMalovic it's slightly too long for a comment then I added an answer but I generally agree with the other guys...probably to keep them open is good enough (or just mark them as _hidden_). In the first part I try to answer your question, in the second part I suggest a different approach (leave them as they are but keep a backup in a safe and different place...maybe Windows Registry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it changing access privileges BUT I strongly suggest to simply keep them open (just be careful to flush the stream after each batch write).

In the first part I try to address directly your question (*"How to prevent..."*) but in the second part I tried to outline a different approach (make your application resilient: keep a backup).

## How to prevent...

Assuming that you're running on Windows to avoid other users to mess with them you should:

- Set the *hidden* attribute. By default hidden files are hidden and many users won't even see them. If you can do it at directory level then even better.
- Change ACL to **deny** `Full access` to `Users` and `Administrators` group. Better if you cherry pick and just leave `Read` permissions. By default Windows pick the most restrictive policy, even when an user belongs to two group, then this will effectively stop everyone to write that file (if you deny also `Read` permissions then they won't even be able to see its content but see later).
- Create a special group (with the required permissions, and only those) with one single user. Be sure that user isn't automatically added to the `Users` group.
- Change your application to impersonate that user when writing those files. If you left the `Read` permissions in-place then code for reading isn't affected.

Don't forget to check with different versions and editions of Windows (`HomeUsers` keep bouncing in my mind.) If your application is a Windows Service then things may be slightly easier, see [eryksun's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168665/prevent-other-processes-and-users-from-accessing-a-file/50170250?noredirect=1#comment87368653_50170250).

You can experiment with all these things simply using Windows Explorer, just find the right balance but don't forget that each single installation is a different world and only God knows what the environment is (but he doesn't know why).

Few obvious drawbacks:

- An administrator can ALWAYS do what he wants then they may find those files and revert permissions. I think (I'm not sure) that System Installer has some special privileges to prevent this but I'm not sure (and I can't imagine how to do it).
- Installation is way more complicate (and you will need one if you don't have). You may do it when application is executed first time but then you will need administrative privileges (just once but probably worse.)
- Your code is more complex.
- More setup means more things that may go wrong, balance this with the effort of your technical support team.
- Updates (and tech support job) will be more complicate.
- Users with certain privileges won't be affected (see [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168665/prevent-other-processes-and-users-from-accessing-a-file/50170250?noredirect=1#comment87368722_50170250)) but this is really a good thing and you shouldn't every try to circumvent it.

## Backup is the key!

Don't forget that if they really want to break your application then they will just delete the application directory...

I think, but I don't know your specific use-case, that maybe you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle. If what you want to prevent the user to corrupt your data files (intentionally or not) then what you need is a **BACKUP**. Save a copy in a different location each time your write them, mark it as *hidden* and live happy. If they're not too big you may even save content directly inside **Windows Registry**. For encrypted/hashed/checksummed files your application can easily detect when they're broken or missing: just restore backup and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and get it done with ACL since that sounds like the best solution.

Comment: IMO is way too complex and I prefer to make application resilient instead of limiting the user (especially administrators, also consider future updates and/or tech support...it'll be much more complicate) but it's just my opinion.

Comment: @AleksandarMalovic, if this is a Windows service, since Vista you can configure it to have its own service SID for use in securing objects. This way you don't even have to create a custom service account; you can just run as one of the standard service accounts (i.e. Local System, Local Service, or Network Service).

Comment: @AleksandarMalovic, bear in mind that no access right is granted to a subject if the file's discretionary access control list (DACL) doesn't grant rights to at least one SID in the subject's effective access token, so deny aces typically aren't needed. Also, implicitly the owner of the file has the right to read and modify the DACL, but this can be controlled via the "Owner Rights" SID.

Comment: @AleksandarMalovic, also, the DACL cannot restrict a user that has SeBackupPrivilege or SeRestorePrivilege enabled and calls `CreateFile` with `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`, or stop a user with SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege enabled from taking control of a file and modifying the DACL. But this is a good thing, and arguably better than denying shared read and write access when opening the file, since you're not locking administrators out, but strongly suggesting that these files shouldn't be modified.

Comment: @eryksun very good points, especially #1 is pretty useful instead of complex installation-time setups. #3 That's a good thing, I think.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks a lot, this is very useful info(especially #1 with the service SID).

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to keep the files open all the time

But keeping them open is a good way that closely follows your intent and requirements.

As long as it's not about hundreds or more, this seems the best option.

The other way is to set the security properties (ACL) but that is messy and requires a higher privilege.

Excluding the Admin is not totally possible and you should not really want that. Avoiding accidental delete or rename is doable, total control is not.

Comment: I don't need the data all the time, so keeping the files open at all times would be just wasting resources.

Comment: So?  A process could open thousands of them (max # file handles is 16 million). Add the (typical) number of files to your question, and anything you can tell about their life cycle.

Comment: There are only a couple of files, they persist indefinitely(just get modified from time to time). I know it won't slow down the machine or something, but I really don't like the approach.

Answer (score 0):

2 Other options are

- Set some permissions in the locations here the files are so that no one can access them
- If all of the files in question will be created by your application, you could check the options in [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx), where you can set the sharing options to `0x00000000` to "Prevent other processes from opening a file or device if they request delete, read, or write access."

If you want to use `CreateFile` I guess you will have to [pinvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateFile) it

Comment: Could you be more specific about the permissions, I haven't been able to find the right configuration for ACL that doesn't also stop me from accessing the file.

Comment: Are you an administrator of your machine?

Comment: @AleksandarMalovic can't you set the permissions on the folder to only allow the account which the application runs under?

Comment: @Bassie The service runs regardless of the account, it needs to work under all user accounts on the machine, and I haven't seen a specific security group for windows services so I don't know if such a permission could be done.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen No, the service is installed on client machines.

Comment: Yes, but you said you couldn't find an ACL that also stopped **you**, so are **you** an administrator of your machine?

Comment: And if a program running under user X creates a file, it cannot stop user X from accessing that file and still have access. Also, by definition, it cannot prevent administrators from accessing the file.